# Find out if all elements of a certain id have the same district

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am looking for a solution for the following problem. I want to know if all objects with a certain ID have the same district:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z001</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>1234</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z001</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>1234</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z001</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>1234</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z001</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>1234</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z001</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>1234</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z002</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>5678</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z002</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>5678</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z002</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>3255</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z002</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>3457</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <OBJECTID>Z002</OBJECTID>
        <DISTRICT>8765</DISTRICT>
    </ROW>
</TABLE>
```

Something like: Look at OBJECTID Z001. Are all DISTRICTs equal? Then choose value of DISTRICT in the transformed xml. When not leave blank.

I have no clue how to manage this task. Thanks for your help in advance.

Fareed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 this is a simple combination of `for-each-group` and `distinct-values`

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/TABLE/ROW" group-by="OBJECTID">
  <xsl:if test="count(distinct-values(current-group()/DISTRICT)) = 1">
    <!-- all district values are the same for this OBJECTID -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with Muenchian grouping. Here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="kObjId" match="DISTRICT" use="../OBJECTID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <n>
      <xsl:variable
        name="uniqueDistricts"
        select="ROW/DISTRICT[generate-id() = 
                             generate-id(key('kObjId', ../OBJECTID)[1])]
                            [not(. != key('kObjId', ../OBJECTID))]" />

      <xsl:apply-templates select="$uniqueDistricts" />
    </n>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DISTRICT">
    <district>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </district>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<n>
  <district>1234</district>
</n>
```